# Make sure that two people belong to the same organization

Tags: database, foreign-keys, constraints, entity-relationship

I'm considering creating an application to manage the agreements signed between the company I am working for and other organizations.

To that end, I created the following EER diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbLIi.png

To be valid, a convention must include both the person who signed it (organization_signatory in table CONVENTION) and a contact person (organization_contact in table CONVENTION).

So my question is: how do I make sure that these two people belong to the same company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add a *constraint*. A Convention organization_contact value appears as an Organization_staff id with some organization value. A Convention organization_signatory value appears as an Organization_staff id with some Organization value. You want those two organization values to be the same.

```
-- Convention(id,...)
fk (organization_contact) references Organization_staff (id)
fk (organization_signatory) references Organization_staff (id)
-- standard SQL but seldom supported
check (
    (select id from Convention c JOIN Organization_staff s
    where c.id = s.organization_contact)
=   (select id from Convention c JOIN Organization_staff s
    where c.id = s.organization_signatory))
```

You don't say what tools you are using so we can't know how to express this in them. Modeling products & SQL DBMSs do not support arbitrary ASSERTION or CHECK constraints well. Re SQL techniques see [Applied Mathematics for Database Professionals](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-uYZcnEt4uQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=applied+mathematics+for+database+professionals). You can search stackoverflow for alternatives to ASSERTION and CHECK constraints.

However it seems reasonable that a Convention would be associated with a particular organization: the organization of its contact and its signatory.

```
fk (organization) references Organization (id)
fk (organization_contact,organization) references Organization_staff (id, organization)
fk (organization_signatory,organization) references Organization_staff (id, organization)
```

SQL requires you to declare (logically redundantly) the FK target in Organization_staff as:

```
unique (id, organization)
```

But you can declare organization in Convention simply for the purpose of making the contact and signatory organization constraint easily declaratively expressible like this. One uses such idioms in SQL for such purposes.