# Maintaining referential integrity and consistency in diamond pattern

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I'm not sure if there's a better term for the situation I fairly commonly find myself in, so I will explain it with a simple example (PostgreSQL).

```sql
CREATE TABLE "table"
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE "column"
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    "table" uuid NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT column_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
ALTER TABLE "column" ADD CONSTRAINT "column_grid_fkey"
    FOREIGN KEY ("table") REFERENCES "table"("id");

CREATE TABLE "row"
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    "table" uuid NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT row_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
ALTER TABLE "row" ADD CONSTRAINT "row_grid_fkey"
    FOREIGN KEY ("table") REFERENCES "table"("id");

CREATE TABLE "cell"
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    "column" uuid NOT NULL,
    "row" uuid NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT cell_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
ALTER TABLE "cell" ADD CONSTRAINT "cell_column_fkey"
    FOREIGN KEY ("column") REFERENCES "column"("id");
ALTER TABLE "cell" ADD CONSTRAINT "cell_row_fkey"
    FOREIGN KEY ("row") REFERENCES "row"("id");
```

In this above setup I of course do not want a single cell to refer to a column and a row in two different tables, so I would like to enforce that they both go to the same table.

One way I can do this is as follows:

```sql
ALTER TABLE "cell" ADD COLUMN "table" uuid NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE "cell" ADD CONSTRAINT "cell_table_fkey"
    FOREIGN KEY ("table") REFERENCES "table"("id");

ALTER TABLE "column" ADD CONSTRAINT "unique_column_column_table"
    UNIQUE ("id", "table");
ALTER TABLE "row" ADD CONSTRAINT "unique_row_row_table"
    UNIQUE ("id", "table");

ALTER TABLE "cell" ADD CONSTRAINT "cell_column_table_fkey"
    FOREIGN KEY ("column", "table") REFERENCES "column"("id", "table");
ALTER TABLE "cell" ADD CONSTRAINT "cell_row_table_fkey"
    FOREIGN KEY ("row", "table") REFERENCES "row"("id", "table");
```

However it involves redundantly storing the table on the cell even though it can be inferred from context. The weird need for additional unique constraints on things that are trivially unique is also annoying.

I was wondering if there was a better way. I was also wondering out of curiosity if the above would be considered normalized or not, you are of course storing redundant data, but it can never desync due to the foreign key constraint, so perhaps it still counts?

My real life examples are more complicated so I went with the above, but I can also provide some of them if the answer is something along the lines of "you should try to avoid this situation depending on your real life use case", but it shows up quite naturally and seems hard to avoid in various situations.

Comment: This is the SQL idiom & this is a faq. Current products don't offer ASSERTION for arbitrary declarative constraints (only triggers for implementing arbitrary constraints) & the specialized SQL constraints (PK, UNIQUE, CHECK, FK) (plus indexing) represent an extremely limited declarative DB facility. The redundancy is just the tradeoff for declarative enforcement.

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? Saying you are "not sure" or "wondering" is not asking a question. Ask 1 question per post. "weird" is unclear. So is "better"--it doesn't mean anything until you define it & then, where/how/why are you stuck evaluating it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make sure that two people belong to the same organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678929/make-sure-that-two-people-belong-to-the-same-organization)